# wrong # args: should be "for start test next command"

Tags: tcl

I had the opening braces of the for loop body in the same line as for loop, but my code still complains.

```
set parallel_count [expr $nb_combi/1024]
for {set j 0} {$j< $parallel_count} {incr j} {
    set k [expr [expr $j+1] * 1024]
    set l [expr $j * 1024]
    set inFile "includefile.$j"
    set inFileId [open $inFile "w"]
    for {set i $l} {$i < $l} {incr i} {
        puts $inFileId  "set DEFINITION_file \"$settings.$i\""
    }
    close $inFileId
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you are describing.

Comment: Also, it's advised to brace your `expr`essions.

Comment: Your code, _as you wrote it above,_ will not produce that error message. I'm going to guess that the code you ran had different spacing. **Tcl is sensitive to whitespace.** Especially to newlines (which some people like to put before the `for` body, despite it making things more difficult for them) but missing a space might also produce that error in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for the quick comments. Not sure what was wrong. the script worked fine after deleting the for loop and re write it.